# Cannot create new AVD on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just installed Android Studio version 0.8.6 and I'm trying to create a new AVD but get error saying `No CPU/ABI system image available for this target`. The only target it lets me choose is `Android 4.4W - API Level 20`.

I can see that there are 9 packages to install in the SDK manager including:

Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 20, revision 1.

But when I try to install after agreeing to the T&C's I get this error log:

```
Downloading SDK Platform Android L Preview, revision 3
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp
Downloading Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 20, revision 1
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp
Downloading Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 20, revision 1
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp
Downloading Android Support Library, revision 20
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp
Downloading Google USB Driver, revision 10
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp
Skipping 'Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API L, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android L Preview, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API L, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android L Preview, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API L, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android L Preview, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API L, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android L Preview, revision 3' which was not installed.
Done. Nothing was installed.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading SDK Platform Android L Preview, revision 3
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp
Downloading Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 20, revision 1
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp
Downloading Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 20, revision 1
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp
Downloading Android Support Library, revision 20
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp
Downloading Google USB Driver, revision 10
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp
Skipping 'Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API L, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android L Preview, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API L, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android L Preview, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API L, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android L Preview, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API L, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android L Preview, revision 3' which was not installed.
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

I'm stuck here and not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first check you have granted writing permission for your C:/> drive and respective directory.
Second you should try running your Android Studio and SDK manager as Administrator.

Comment: Thanks, yes had to run as administrator